# How can I enable Live Reload or Hot Reload without having to shake my phone?

Tags: react-native

I started using React Native for about 2 weeks, and sometimes I need to reinstall the app, then shake the phone again and enable the live reload.

It's funny at the first week, but then it gets boring to have to shake the phone while developing.

Is there any config file which I can set those development properties to be always enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a closed issue related to open the menu by pressing the screen with 3 fingers. You can check if in the latest versions (or in expo) it is working: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10191

Also there are other 3 solutions:

1) You can run `adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU` in your terminal

2) Try this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10191#issuecomment-328854286

> Open RN dev menu
>
> /usr/local/bin/adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU Reload RN
>
> /usr/local/bin/adb shell input keyevent 82 /usr/local/bin/adb shell
>   input keyevent 66 /usr/local/bin/adb shell input keyevent 66 (reload
>   was not always working without adding the last line)
>
> In Preferences->Keyboard->Keyboard shortcuts you can then map these
>   services to keyboard shortcuts. I added the shortcuts for the context
>   of my editor (Webstorm) and React Native debugger. In these programs I
>   can now press Ctrl+D to show the developer menu and Ctrl+R to reload
>   which works perfectly.

3) Or you can try this (Android only) https://medium.com/delivery-com-engineering/react-native-stop-shaking-your-phone-1f4863140146

> 1. Set up an Automator Service by opening Automator, clicking “New
>      Document”, and choosing “Service”.
> 2. Find and select the “Run Shell Script” action. Choose “no input” for “Service receives” and enter: /usr/local/bin/adb shell input
>      keyevent 82 If adb is located elsewhere in your system, change the
>      path to adb. You can find out with: $ which adb
> 3. Save and remember what name you give the action.
> 4. Open “System Preferences”, go to “Keyboard” and select the “Shortcuts” tab. Select “Services” on the left column and find your
>      service by name.
> 5. Click where it says “none” and enter the keyboard shortcut you want to use. Make it something unique or it will conflict with an existing
>      shortcut.
>
> Notes: Android only Must be plugged in If you’ve never run the
>   following with this device, run it first before trying the shortcut: $
>   adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice, I personally liked the first solution, but as I asked, isn't there any way to set the live reload default to be always enabled?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. I couldn't find any reference in the docs.

Comment: I found this issue on GitHub https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2064

But I couldn't understand where I can find this config, also the link mentioned is broken... :/

Answer (score 8):

You can add hot reload function with hold the `menu` button in your phone 
it show the developer menu setting for react native app

after that you can select the hotreload function

or you can type this on your terminal

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

Answer (score 0):

run adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU in your terminal